# Cursor for loop error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to write cursor that would insert into table, but I am receiving error, need help with this. Error that I am receiving is ORA-06550.

```
    DECLARE
    CURSOR cur_rating IS
           SELECT bc.name, bc.title, bc.checkoutdate, bc.returneddate,    
               b.categoryname,b.publisher, ba.authorname
               FROM bookshelf_checkout bc INNER JOIN bookshelf b
               ON bc.title = b.title
               INNER JOIN bookshelf_author ba
               ON bc.title = ba.title
               FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
            lv_totdays_num NUMBER(4) := 0;
            lv_rating_txt VARCHAR2(2);
    BEGIN
       FOR rec_rating IN cur_rating LOOP
           lv_totdays_num := rec_rating.returneddate -  
           rec_rating.checkoutdate;
       IF lv_totdays_num <= 10 THEN lv_rating_txt := 'DR';
       ELSIF lv_totdays_num <= 25 THEN lv_rating_txt := 'CR';
       ELSIF lv_totdays_num <= 35 THEN lv_rating_txt := 'BR';
       ELSE lv_rating_txt := 'A';
       END IF;
       INSERT INTO bookshelf_audit (title, publisher, categoryname,  
                                   new_rating, auditdate)
       VALUES      (rec_rating.title, rec_rating.publisher,   
                 rec_rating.categoryname, lv_rating_txt, sysdate)
       WHERE CURRENT OF cur_rating;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
    END;
```

Comment: please paste the entire error message:  ORA-06550 line number ? column ?  There is a missing semicolon in INSERT clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `where` clause from your `insert ... values` statement:

```
INSERT INTO bookshelf_audit
    (title, publisher, categoryname,  
     new_rating, auditdate)
VALUES
    (rec_rating.title, rec_rating.publisher,   
     rec_rating.categoryname, lv_rating_txt, sysdate)
WHERE CURRENT OF cur_rating;
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO bookshelf_audit
    (title, publisher, categoryname,  
     new_rating, auditdate)
VALUES
    (rec_rating.title, rec_rating.publisher,   
     rec_rating.categoryname, lv_rating_txt, sysdate);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you @William Robertson!

Answer (score 2):

The `WHERE CURRENT OF` clause in an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement states that the most recent row fetched from the table should be updated or deleted :

```
UPDATE table_name
  SET set_clause
  WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name;
```

OR

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name;
```

but not applicable for an `INSERT` statement.
So, remove `WHERE CURRENT OF cur_rating` part only, your code will run. That's make your `INSERT` statement as :

```
INSERT INTO bookshelf_audit (title, publisher, categoryname,  
                                   new_rating, auditdate)
       VALUES      (rec_rating.title, rec_rating.publisher,   
                 rec_rating.categoryname, lv_rating_txt, sysdate);
```